# Interface implementation

Tags: java, interface

I have been asked the following question:

a) The interface IntSet has a single method called isElem. The method takes a
single parameter of type int and returns a boolean result.
Define the interface IntSet in full.

So far for my answer I have. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
  public interface Intset {

  public abstract boolean isElem (int a)

}
```

Comment: You forgot the `;` at the end of the method declaration.  Also, `public` and `abstract` are optional.  `Intset` and `IntSet` are two different names.  Otherwise it's OK.

Comment: You've got a minor typo: the question asks for `IntSet`, but you defined `Intset`.

Answer (score 4):

The correct solution is:

```
public interface IntSet {

  public abstract boolean isElem (int a);

}
```

You forgot the ; at the end of the method definition, and you had a small typo in the class name.

Note that the keywords `public` and `abstract` are optional and discouraged in this case.

Comment: The solution is correct, but the extraneous modifiers `public` and `abstract` are discouraged as per the JLS.

Comment: Are you sure that they are discouraged and not only optional?

Comment: Optional and discouraged. See section 9.4 of the JLS.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add it to my answer for the sake of completeness

Answer (score 1):

apart from the trailing semi-colon, you have completed the question.

```
 public interface Intset {

  public abstract boolean isElem (int a);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to write `;` and in interface methods are by default pulbic and abstract so

you can write

```
public interface IntSet{
    boolean isElem(int val);
}
```

or

```
public interface IntSet{
    public abstract boolean isElem(int val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every method in an interface is by default public and abstract

```
public interface IntSet {
  boolean isElem (int a);
}
```

I would drop the `public abstract` from the code.  You rarely see this, since it is redundant.

From the Java Language Specification, [Section 9.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/interfaces.doc.html):

> Every method declaration in the body
>   of an interface is implicitly
>   abstract, so its body is always represented by a semicolon, not a block.
>
> Every method declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly
>   public.

and the grammar:

```
InterfaceMemberDeclaration:
    ConstantDeclaration
    AbstractMethodDeclaration
    ClassDeclaration 
    InterfaceDeclaration
    ;
```

also demonstrates all methods declared in an interface are abstract.

Answer (score -1):

```
public interface IntSet{
    bool isElem(int val);
}
```

Comment: My mistake, missed that it was tagged under java. Works fine in C#, appreciate the down vote.